# vega-lite deneb grouped bar chart - Labels positioning

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, deneb

i am still polishing this project:

[Vega-Lite / Deneb grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170255/vega-lite-deneb-grouped-bar-chart/76170781#76170781)

(The solution code from above link is pasted at the bottom + image).

I would like to add data labels to this visual showing project date but depending on Country slicer and conditions below i would like to dynamically adjust "dx". **Is it possible? **

My conditions
1 - if _Date_Target is > or < than _Date_Today  (shows if bar point left or right)

2 - Country slicer is selected or not   (if selected then scale of x-axis is different than if all countries are visible)

3 - Number of days between _Date_Target and _Date_Today (determines the lenght of the bar)

The need is coming from the fact that in some combinations e.g small difference between today and target my labels are not visible or position is not correct.
So the basic design is to show them inside of the bar at its end.
But if the target is close then outside of the bar.

So for example:

if _date_target > today and slicer is selected and difference between target and today is < 200 days then i would like dx with value A1

else
if _date_target > today and slicer is selected and difference between target and today is >= 200 days then i would like dx with value A2

else
if _date_target > today and slicer is NOT selected and difference between target and today is <50 then dx with value B1

else
if _date_target > today and slicer is NOT selected and difference between target and today is >=50 then dx with value B2

So the above logic is only for bars pointing right (target in the future)
Then again i would need similar logic for bars pointing left.

**Is there a simpler method to achieve the result?**  Maybe it is posible to compare length of bar mark with length of text mark? and if difference is too big than positioning is adjusted?

Code and image from the previous question:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "country": "BBB",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-02-20",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      },
      {
        "name": "A1",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-01-10",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "country": "BBB",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-08-21",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      },
      {
        "name": "E",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-09-01",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      },
      {
        "name": "F",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-08-15",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      },
      {
        "name": "G",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-11-20",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03"
      }
    ]
  },
  "spacing": -8,
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "country",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"title": null, "labelAngle": 0}
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "height": {"step": 25},
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
        "encoding": {
          "y": {
            "field": "name",
            "type": "nominal",
            "axis": {"title": null, "grid": false, "tickBand": "extent"}
          },
          "x": {
            "field": "_Date_Today",
            "type": "temporal",
            "axis": {
              "title": null,
              "format": "%b-%y",
              "grid": true,
              "gridWidth": 1,
              "gridColor": "grey",
              "gridDash": [4, 4],
              "gridOpacity": {
                "condition": {
                  "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                  "value": 0.5
                },
                "value": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "x2": {"field": "_Date_Target"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "_Date_Today", "type": "temporal"}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}},
  "config": {"view": {"stroke": "silver"}}
}
```

[image]

I've tried using measures for that, "dx" + "condition" + "and",  "condition" with array [], also variations of "expr". Color of text is already conditionally formatted to black and white depending on conditions (using a measure inside "condition").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code so that the target dates appear inside each bar. You can add some extra logic on the expression if you want the target date to appear outside the bars.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "country": "BBB",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-01-20",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "Y"
      },
      {
        "name": "A1",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-01-10",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "Y"
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "country": "BBB",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-08-21",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "N"
      },
      {
        "name": "E",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-09-01",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "N"
      },
      {
        "name": "F",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-08-15",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "N"
      },
      {
        "name": "G",
        "country": "AAA",
        "_Date_Target": "2023-11-20",
        "_Date_Today": "2023-05-03",
        "name_focus": "N"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.name + '|' + datum.name_focus", "as": "name_full"},
    {
      "calculate": "(datetime(datum._Date_Target)-datetime(datum._Date_Today)) / (24*60*60*1000)",
      "as": "days_difference"
    }
  ],
  "spacing": -10,
  "facet": {
    "row": {
      "field": "country",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "header": {"title": null, "labelAngle": 0}
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "height": {"step": 25},
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": true},
        "encoding": {
          "y": {
            "field": "name_full",
            "type": "nominal",
            "axis": {
              "title": null,
              "grid": false,
              "tickBand": "extent",
              "labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '|')[0]",
              "labelFontWeight": {
                "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ?'bold':'normal'"
              },
              "labelColor": {
                "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? '#4c78a8':'gray'"
              },
              "labelFontSize": {
                "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? '12':'10'"
              },
              "labelPadding": {
                "expr": "indexof(datum.label, '|Y') !== -1 ? '5':'0'"
              }
            }
          },
          "x": {
            "field": "_Date_Today",
            "type": "temporal",
            "axis": {
              "title": null,
              "format": "%b-%y",
              "grid": true,
              "gridWidth": 1,
              "gridColor": "grey",
              "gridDash": [4, 4],
              "gridOpacity": {
                "condition": {
                  "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
                  "value": 0.5
                },
                "value": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "x2": {"field": "_Date_Target"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red"},
        "encoding": {"x": {"field": "_Date_Today", "type": "temporal"}}
      },
      {
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "right",
          "baseline": "middle",
          "dx": {
            "expr": "datum.days_difference > 0 ? 15 : (datum.days_difference < 0 ? -35 : 0)"
          },
          "color": {"expr": "datum.days_difference > 100 ? 'white' : 'orange'"}
        },
        "encoding": {
          "y": {"field": "name_full", "type": "nominal"},
          "text": {
            "field": "_Date_Target",
            "type": "temporal",
            "format": "%d-%b"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent"}},
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "silver"},
    "style": {"cell": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
  }
}
```

Comment: I removed the second answer since it was off topic.
Your comment:
Thanks Adam!! It is a pity that we cannot include the 'slicer selection' condition as this changes a lot in how the chart is displayed. Current way i' am dealing with this is using measures in PBI: 1. _Date_Target 2._Date_Today Code: "dx" : { "expr": "datum._Date_Target < datum._Date_Today? 5 : -5" } + similar condition applied to "align". Using difference between dates is great option (DAX's DATEDIFF) Also i've added background so labels are always visible. All in all Deneb rocks!:)

Comment: My example shows you how to move around the bar labels conditionally. You could add some logic to a dax and pass that value through instead. If you need more help just ask. Please mark the answer as complete.